# $T = \operatorname{diag}\{p_1, p_2, \ldots\} \oplus A$ with $p_j \geqslant 0$ and $A \leqslant 0$

Tags: proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $\mathcal H$ be a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

The proof of Corollary $3$ in [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042145) paper claims that a given compact Hermitian operator $T$ can be assumed to be of the form (by considering $-T$ if necessary)
$$T = \operatorname{diag}\{p_1, p_2, \ldots\} \oplus A \tag{1}$$
with $p_j \geqslant 0$ and $A \leqslant 0$ (not excluding the possibility that $A$ is absent).

How is this proved?

By the spectral theorem, I know that $T$ is unitarily equivalent to
$$T_0:= \operatorname{diag}\{d_1, d_2, \ldots\}$$
with $d_n  \in \Bbb R$ and $d_n \to 0$, but I haven't been able to use this to get something like $(1)$.

Also, are they writing $T$ as $\operatorname{diag}\{p_1, p_2, \ldots\} \oplus A$ only up to unitary equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in $(1)$ is obtained simply by separating the negative $d_j$ from the nonnegative ones. As in
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&-2&0&0\\ 0&0&-3&0\\ 0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix} 
\simeq \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&4&0&0\\ 0&0&-2&0\\ 0&0&0&-3\end{bmatrix} .
$$

As for unitary equivalence, every time you express an operator in coordinates you are choosing an orthonormal basis. So yes, it is "up to unitary equivalence" if you want for some reason to stick with a particular orthonormal basis.

Comment: In that case, $A$ is also a diagonal operator? Where's the direct sum coming from? It would be helpful if you could provide some details for the direct sum decomposition, perhaps.

Comment: Diagonal, with respect to what? Every selfadjoint compact operator is "diagonal". A direct sum consist simply of determining two direct summads; in this case, two orthogonal subspaces. So given any orthonormal basis, you split it in two subsets and that determines a direct sum of the corresponding subspaces.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks. Could you please explain how the author writes
$$T = \left(\operatorname{diag}\left\{p_1 + 1, -\frac{1}{2}, p_3 + \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{4} , p_5 + \frac{1}{5}\ldots\right\} \oplus A\right) +  \left(\operatorname{diag}\left\{-1, p_2 + \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}, p_4 + \frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{5}\ldots\right\} \oplus 0\right)$$ though?

Comment: (2/2) It is not clear that $\operatorname{diag}\left\{p_1 + 1, -\frac{1}{2}, p_3 + \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{4} , p_5 + \frac{1}{5}\ldots\right\} $ and $\operatorname{diag}\left\{-1, p_2 + \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}, p_4 + \frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{5}\ldots\right\}$ act on the same space.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. They are defined to act on the same base. If the author writes two diagonal operators, one after the other, without any clarification, it should be obvious that they are diagonal with respect to the same basis.